# Flowplayer HTML5 Video Not Found

Tags: javascript, html, flowplayer

I have flowplayer running on a page in a slight variation of the playlist demo on their site, and for the most part it seems okay.

However, when I pause the video and switch to another video in the playlist on Chrome, once in a while, it will say HTML5 video not found (it will list the current video, not the one selected).

This will proceed to break the player and the page, forcing a refresh. The message also seems to show up on page refresh sometimes, but that doesn't matter much since it will be reloaded.

I am not sure what is wrong, but I have two theories.

1) MP4 file not streamable
  -possible but unlikely considering I can jump around the video easily
2) Timeout from S3
  -maybe, but I don't see any errors.

Has anyone seen this/know how to debug it?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do would be to test this in another browser.  If it works ok then it will be a video compatibility issue with the browser.

Mozilla has a very good article on [Media formats supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats). In it it states:

> The MP4 container format with the H.264 video codec and either the AAC audio codec or the MP3 audio codec is natively supported by Internet Explorer, Safari and Chrome, but Chromium and Opera do not support the format. Firefox will soon support the format, but only when a third-party decoder is available.

For the best cross browser support you really need two video formats `MP4` and `WebM`